# How to update the null timestamp with current timestamp in postgres(pg-promise)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

When I am trying to update my DB field **date_read(D-type = timestamp with time zone)** which is initially null, with the current timestamp then I am getting the below error.

**“message”: “column \“date_read\” is of type timestamp with time zone but the expression is of type text”**

```
const object1= Object.keys(req.body)[0]; //oytput = uuid

    const upodatedObj = [ { uuid: 123, data_read: true, date_read: “2021-04-16T11:15:30.658+00Z” },{ uuid: 124, data_read: true, date_read: “2021-04-16T11:15:30.658+00Z” },{ uuid: 125, data_read: true, date_read: “2021-04-16T11:15:30.658+00Z” } ]


    const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([`?${object1}`, “is_read”, “date_read”], {
      table: “my-table”,
    });

    const update =
      pgp.helpers.update(upodatedObj, cs) +
      `WHERE v.${object1} = t.${object1}`;

    await pool.none(update);
```

but getting the error while updating.
Looking for the solution to how I can update the date_read field with the current timestamp( “2021-04-16T11:15:30.658+00Z”).

Comment: did you try to use the function NOW()? https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-now/

Comment: @user3100287 can you update the above code if possible? because I am getting the error NOW of undefined.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pg-promise, but I would do: `pool.none('UPDATE my-table SET is_read = true, date_read = NOW() WHERE uuid = $1', [object1])`

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a solution with pg-promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper definition for the column-set (see [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) and [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html)):

```js
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    '?first',
    'second',
    {name: 'date_read', mod: ':raw', init: ()=> 'NOW()'}
], {
    table: 'my-table',
});
```

Comment: still getting the same error.“message”: “column \“date_read\” is of type timestamp with time zone but the expression is of type text”

Comment: @majidbeg I have updated the answer, should be good now ;)